# Can I upgrade MacBook Pro 13" with HDD

Tags: macbook-pro, upgrade, hdd

I'm planning to buy MacBook Pro 13" 256GB SSD but i find it too expensive. I thought that it would be better if i buy 128gb SSD and upgrade it with an HDD storage. Is that possible? If not, is Apple still selling the old MBP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest [MacBook Pro 13" (MacBookPro12,1)](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i5-2.7-13-early-2015-retina-display-specs.html) comes with a special internal HD interface based on PCIe and uses a special form factor for the SSD. Check the [ifixit](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Retina+Display+Mid+2014+SSD+Replacement/27849) replacement guide how it looks like. This replacement guide shows a MacBook Pro 2014 but the SSD in the recent model looks similar.
So internally there is neither space nor an appropriate interface to upgrade it with HDD storage.

The last MacBook Pro 13" with a SATA interface and an HDD is the [MacBookPro9,2](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i7-2.9-13-mid-2012-unibody-usb3-specs.html). Check the link in the [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/191076/can-i-upgrade-macbook-pro-13-with-hdd/191077#191077) provided by Tuan Anh Tran where to purchase it.

Answer (score 1):

The old Macbook Pro is still available on [Apple Store](http://store.apple.com/us/buy-mac/macbook-pro?product=MD101LL/A&step=config#).